# Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window' invalid mode

Tags: javascript, fetch

All of a sudden, all my fetch request in the browser throws `Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window' invalid mode`. They worked fine before. Anyone could give a hint on this? my code is as below:

```
function request(params) {
  let { api, method, data } = params
  let localParm = {
    method: method,    
    mode: { mode: 'no-cors' },
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: typeof Headers !== 'undefined' ? new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }) : { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  }
  let url = apiNames[api] || api
  if (method == "POST") {
    localParm.body = toQueryString(data)
  } else if (method == "GET") {       
    if (data) {
      url += ("?" + toQueryString(data || {}))
    }
  }
  const reqFunc = method === 'jsonp' ? fetchJsonp : fetch;
  return reqFunc(url, localParm).then((response) => {
    if (response.status === 200 || response.ok === true) {
      try {
        return response.json()        
      }catch(e){
        console.log('11')
      }
    } else {
        console.log('22')      
    }
  }).then((res) => {       
    return res        
  })
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing quotation mark after `22` :)

Comment: my bad, the actual code is with the quotation.

Comment: This happened to one of my apps in both Chrome and Firefox after recent updates. But I am using `credentials: 'same-origin'` as listed in the Fetch spec. User reported problem. Checked to verify it was working, installed Chrome update, and now I get this error every time. Seems a browser bug to me.

Comment: OK, the actual wrong thing in the code is due to  `mode: { mode: 'no-cors' }`, which is not correctly written, the right way is `mode: 'no-cors'`

Answer (score 2):

Remove CORS mode from your header. Seems you start to use stage-0 or stage-2 in your JavaScript specification. In that specification fetch for some reason does not allow CORS mode.

```
 let localParm = {
    method: method,    
    mode: { mode: 'no-cors' },
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: typeof Headers !== 'undefined' ? new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }) : { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  }
```

should look like

```
let localParm = {
    method: method,    
    credentials: 'include', ....
```